# C++ text decoder only taking one line from a text file

Tags: c++, text-files

Im working on a two part program that uses an encoder do encode a text file then a decoder to decode the text file. However i cannot get my decoder to read the whole text file it just reads the first line. How do i fix this, ive played around with the loops but it is not helping me.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string lineFromFile; 
    fin.open("secret.txt");
    if (!fin.good()) throw "I/O error";
    fout.open("secret.txt", ios::app); 
    if (!fout.good()) throw "I/O error"; 

    while (fin.good())
    {
        getline(fin, lineFromFile); 
        for (int i = 0; i < lineFromFile.length(); i++) // for each char in the string...
            lineFromFile[i]--; // bump the ASCII code by 1
        fout << lineFromFile << endl;     
    }//while

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the stream in the first iteration (i.e., after reading the first line). *Then* you open the output stream to *write* the first line. Only *then* do you reach the end of the while-loop, at which time `fin.good()` cannot be true anymore since you closed `fin`.

The loop should contain *only* the reading and writing. Opening done before the loop, closing done after.

Additional suggestion: Use proper indenting, it helps understanding the control flow.

Comment: ok i made  some changes but still not sending the whole text file

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are reading and writing from the same file: `secret.txt`. I do not know what the expected behaviour is but when I ran the code it was infinite, which makes some sense as you are appending.

Try changing the ouput stream, `fout`, to a different file name.

The while loop that currently processes the file will process a final invalid read as you do not check if `getline()` was successful until the loop condition. I would suggest changing to:

```
for (;;)
{
    getline(fin, lineFromFile); 
    if (!fin.good())
    {
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lineFromFile.length(); i++)
        lineFromFile[i]--;
    fout << lineFromFile << endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that because another file handle,`fout`, accesses the file to which `fin` is tied, `fin` is closed as a side-effect. Either that, or because `fout` appends to the file, the file pointer is pointed to the end of the file, and so because there is no more input to read, the loop ends.
(These are hypotheses; I am not familiar enough with the specifics of C++ I.O. to conclusively say what is happening.)

If you are supposed to replace the original file with an encoded version, I recommend setting the file tied to `fout` to a temporary file for the duration of your code above, closing both `fin` and `fout`, and then copying the file associated with `fout` over the file associated with `fin`.

Otherwise, just tie `fout` to a different filename than `fin`, such as `"encoded.txt"`.